# Coded UI Test replacing string of ints with double

Tags: c#, csv, casting, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing a test for a webpage and I'm replacing some values from the recorded steps with csv values.

The problem is in the record I got this value:

```
public string UITboxNDocEditText = "866700228007551009280449220150921009003761527571";
```

and in the csv I got this value:

```
866700000007551009280449220150921009000001527571
```

the line I'm using to replace the value is this one:

```
this.UIMap.InsBDFParams.UITboxNDocEditText = TestContext.DataRow["n_b"].ToString();
```

the problem is that the script is instead writing this value : **8,66700000007551E+47**

I tried casting the `TestContext.DataRow` line to a `string` instead of using the `.ToString()` method like this : `(string)TestContext.DataRow["n_b"];`  but got an error complaining about casting from a double so I assume the script is considering my value to be a double.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that encapsulating `866700000007551009280449220150921009000001527571` with double quotes solved the issue :

`"866700000007551009280449220150921009000001527571"`.

I think it treats it as a string so it doesn't mess up the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format the string, `F0`, the `0` stands for zero decimal places:

```
 this.UIMap.InsBDFParams.UITboxNDocEditText = 
        ((double)TestContext.DataRow["n_b"])
              .ToString("F0");
```

Comment: I'm getting a "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments error =/

Comment: data type is a double, yes? what .net framework version do you use?

Comment: Yes ! `System.Double` just checked.

Comment: I'd guess that it's a boxed `double`, so you'd have to cast to `double` to be able to use the `ToString` that takes a format string.

Comment: It gave an incorrect number =/ I found this solved it :
`string NumDoc = this.UIMap.InsBFParams.UITboxNDocEditText;` and replacing to `NumDoc = TestContext.DataRow["n_b"].ToString();`

Comment: any ideas on what it could have been ? You can still answer it correctly !